# The WMS Access URLs and Data Format for viz.globe.gov

Tags: wms, globe

As I'm reading there are two popular formats for GIS data: KML and WMS. [This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7199/Free-Maps-from-the-Web-Using-Web-Mapping-Service) says the access URL for the GLOBE WMS `GetCapabilities` is at `http://viz.globe.gov/viz-bin/wmt.cgi?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities`. However the `/viz-bin/wmt.cgi` does not exist anymore.

The questions:

- Has the WMS URL moved?
- Has the data format changed? If it does,what is the new format of this site?

Edit: More questions:

- Is the site still good for testing WMS service against?
- What is the other best server for testing?

Comment: not sure that anyone on this site will have information about the folder structure of that website. Try the root url and look for their mapping links perhaps

Comment: then against which webserver do you usually test your client code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial link on http://www.globe.gov that takes you to http://www.globe.gov/documents/10157/7349361/Viz+tutorial.pdf

That, plus the use of google maps (note the watermark in the bottom left corner, and the HTML source for the http://viz.globe.gov page), suggests to me that the site isn't intended to support programmatic access to the base map.

There are plenty of other good WMS (or TMS) servers. One list is at http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/AvailableWMSServices - a google search will give you many more.

Comment: Nice Answer. very complete